# passar valor php para o js dando erro

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, array

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
width: 100%;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 5px;
}

th {text-align: left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','peter','abc123','my_db');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"banco_dados");
$sql="SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE id = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>nome</th>
<th>snome</th>
<th>idade</th>
<th>cidade</th>
<th>estado</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['nome'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['snome'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['idade'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['cidade'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['estado'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
$json[] = $row;
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);

$teste = $row['nome'];

?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   var dados = <?php echo json_encode($json)?>;
   alert(dados[2].nome);
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

veja nas ultimas 8 linhas me retorna um alert mais sem dados nas variveis so retorna             isso 
é que preciso trabalharcom esses dados em um js entende.

vc sabe como posso passar esses vlores para o js?

Comment: A pergunta importante aqui e: por que você quer exibir um alerta JavaScript com a tag HTML <td>?? Ou, se esse alerta deveria ser dentro do while pra pegar o $row['nome'], por que você quer exibir um alerta JavaScript pra cada linha da consulta? Não faz sentido.

Comment: é que eu quero usar esses dados em um painel de usuario o alert é só para saber se tem como passar o valor pro js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, se eu entendi bem sua pergunta, você precisa pegar os dados que vêm do back end e usá-los em uma função js, certo?

Um opção é gerar um JSON com esses dados e manipulá-los de acordo à sua necessidade. Vou dar um exemplo de como ficaria o seu loop while no php:

```
$json = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['nome'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['snome'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['idade'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['cidade'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['estado'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  $json[] = $row; //adiciona o row dentro do objeto json
}
```

Depois disso, para que esse objeto fique acessível no js, abra uma tag script e escreva:

```
var dados = <?php echo json_encode($json)?>;
```

Assim, você pode acessar qualquer valor usando:

```
alert(dados[0].nome);
```

Substitua o 0 pelo número do row que você quiser usar. O objeto json é independente da tabela que foi impressa no HTML, de forma que você não precisa se preocupar caso precise mudar algo nela.

Comment: amigo nao esta me retornando nada nesse alert que voce me disse, entao coloquei assim para ver se funcionava mas retornou null, alert(dados); mas seu alert nao parece funcionar nao.

Comment: Verifique no código fonte da página se a variável dados está sendo definida corretamente dentro da tag de script. Basicamente você está imprimindo um array PHP para um objeto JSON.

Comment: amigo o console do chrome diz que o numero "0" esta null (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null ) o alert dessa forma alert(dados[1].nome;) retorna null o javascript esta rodando dentro das tags normalmente mas o alert esta errado. sera que estamos tentando acessar de um geito errado?

Comment: Abra o código fonte da página (ctrl+u no chrome) e atualize sua resposta com o valor que está sendo impresso na linha: var dados = <?php echo json_encode($json)?>;

Comment: retorna isso >></tr></table> <script type="text/javascript">
   var dados = null;
   alert(dados[2].nome);
  </script>
significa que  json nao esta esta com dados do php?

Comment: Exatamente. A função json_encode basicamente transforma um array em uma string em formato JSON. Veja se sua query está retornando resultados.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você está definindo `$teste = $row['nome'];` fora do *while*, ou seja, já não existe mais a variável `$row['nome']`. O ideal é você definir a variável fora do *while* (antes), e dentro dele, atribuir um valor. Dessa forma:

```
$teste = "Erro ao pegar o valor"; // Cria uma variável com um valor inicial
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['nome'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['snome'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['idade'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['cidade'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['estado'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  $teste = $row['nome']; // Atribui um novo valor para a variável
}
```

Dessa forma, mesmo se a consulta der errado, a variável `$teste` existirá, e ela irá automaticamente exibir uma mensagem dizendo que a consulta não foi bem sucedida.

Comment: mesmo assim nao passa o valor para o alert amigo.

Comment: Por que você deveria usar a variável `$teste` no `alert`...

Comment: a verdade é que eu quero passar o valor da variavel php pro javascript seja no alert ou simplesmente na variavel js.